# Are farmers in the Great Plains aware of the Dust Bowl?

Tags: united-states, public-opinion, environmental-policy, agriculture

I'm curious if farmers in the Great Plains are aware today of the history of the [Dust Bowl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_Bowl), including its causes. Are there any surveys or polls on the matter among farmers, like there are (also among farmers) e.g. for [climate change in general](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/40513/18373).

Some [interviewing on PBS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7Uwg8BT6qQ) suggests that some are aware, but this could be a pretty biased sample.

---

Interesting enough, I found [a survey](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23780129) that asked respondents to draw it, but it wasn't limited to farmers:

> Data for this study were obtained from a questionnaire
>   administered to 372 voluntary participants in 93 counties
>   of the Great Plains. The 93-county study area correlates
>   with counties of Colorado, Kansas, New Mexico, Oklahoma,
>   and Texas that have more than 50% of their area
>   included in any one of the three wind erosion areas identified
>   on Worster’s ([1979] 1982) Dust Bowl map. Because
>   the identification of spatial variation across the study
>   area was of paramount importance, participants were
>   obtained via convenience sampling at each of the county
>   courthouses in the 93 study counties. [...]
>
> Maps were completed by 355 of 372 respondents. The
>   remaining 17 respondents were not familiar with the Dust
>   Bowl term and subsequently could not portray it on a map.

Nor did ask them any questions about its history.

And since someone questioned the relevance of this question to politics in comments; that paper includes and concludes with

> Many counties in the
>   historic Dust Bowl region have witnessed a significant
>   influx of Hispanic persons in recent years (Haverluk and
>   Trautman 2008). Interviews conducted for this research
>   suggest that these new arrivals rarely have knowledge of
>   the Dust Bowl, thus further contributing to the drop-off
>   in knowledge of the human-environment relationship in
>   the region. [...]
>
> the documentation
>   of an eroding knowledge-base regarding what
>   is arguably the United States’ most acute environmental
>   disaster is cause for concern. In spite of the appearance
>   of “conquering geography” in the region (Lewis 1979)
>   by the application of center-pivot irrigation, the region’s
>   documented history of widespread, long-term drought
>   events suggests that it is a merely a matter of time until the
>   next challenge is presented to the human existence on the
>   Great Plains. When the uncertainties of climate change,
>   increasing energy costs, and groundwater depletion are
>   considered as well, one wonders if the residents of the
>   Great Plains can afford not to know their past.

"Goundwater depletion" refers to the [Ogallala Aquifer](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-ogallala-aquifer/).

Comment: This seems to be a question about farming or education, not about politics.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I think questions about public-opinion of issues that are relevant in today's politics are on-topic.

Comment: I imagine that asking a farmer if they know about the Dust Bowl is a lot like asking a stockbroker if they know about the Great Depression. The answer is that they probably know more about it than you do.