# Brexit and backstop: would changes require unanimous approval by all EU countries? Does Ireland hold a veto?

Tags: brexit, northern-ireland, republic-of-ireland, ireland

A number of EU rules need to be agreed to unanimously:  new members, treaties, taxation, IIRC.

Ireland (the Republic, not NI) has repeatedly stated its concerns with the re-introduction of a hard border, a concern the backstop was designed to avoid.

The new UK Prime Minister Boris Johnson talks a fair bit about engaging with the EU to remove that backstop and talking to Merkel and Macron.  But ultimately, is Ireland fully capable of blocking a Brexit deal that it considers unfavorable, just by exercising a veto?  In which case, why the emphasis on discussing the backstop with the EU as a whole or Germany and France, if Ireland can pull the plug at any time?

Does Ireland have an explicit and formal veto power on amending the backstop agreement if it feels it goes against its interests?  If so, seems to me as if Boris Johnson needs to sell whatever he's selling to them first and they've been unambiguously critical of adjusting the backstop.

Or would such arrangement fall under EU majority rules, rather than needing unanimous approval?

As I recall, the EU-Canada trade deal came very close to being derailed due Wallon (Belgium) objections concerning either cattle or dairy.  This wasn't resolved until Belgium got some concessions and everyone more or less acknowledged Belgium's right to veto.  I can't see anyone forcing Ireland to swallow concessions about something that's as important to them.

Note that I am not talking about future treaties the EU and the UK might enter into past Brexit.  That's an unanimity-required domain.

Comment: related [why-is-boris-johnson-visiting-only-paris-berlin-if-every-member-of-the-eu-need](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/43825/why-is-boris-johnson-visiting-only-paris-berlin-if-every-member-of-the-eu-need)  but I think they, like me, also confused extension unanimity with agreement unanimity.

Comment: To be fair, Boris Johnson talked with Irish leaders, over the phone, at least.

Comment: "If so, seems to me as if Boris Johnson needs to sell whatever he's selling to them first and they've been unambiguously critical of adjusting the backstop." This also assumes that what Johnson is selling is for the EU's consumption at all, which isn't clear. He might in fact be building a story that puts the EU (and its two most visible leaders) in a negative light for how "unreasonable" they are for his own citizens to consume and to strengthen his own political position.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why in the title you refer to Euro countries (which I read as "those countries that use the euro as currency") rather than the countries of the European Union, of which a few does not use the euro?

Comment: @aCVn  not particularly Euro here just being shorthand for European - it's a long title.  feel free to edit.

Comment: @Ellesedil Considering how he painted Theresa May as incompetent for not getting a better deal, but now where Johnson can't even get the EU to talk about a better deal it's all "EU is unreasonable, inflexible, etc. ", I'd say it's all theatre aimed at the British public.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- The withdrawal agreement requires a qualified majority by the remaining EU members ([Article 50](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:12012M050&from=EN) section 4).
- Any extension of the negotiating period must be unanimous ([Article 50](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:12012M050&from=EN) section 3).
- EU members have been known to engage in "blackmail" to get an effective veto in areas which do not require unanimity by [threatening a veto](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-europe-migrants-italy-eu/italy-threatens-to-veto-eu-budget-without-changes-in-immigration-policy-di-maio-idUSKCN1LC1MD) in *unrelated* areas which do require unanimity.
- Various EU members have publicly declared that they [back](https://www.ft.com/content/34a22284-0ff3-36a7-9e33-c010bbb2cd23) the Republic of Ireland and that they will agree only to deals which satisfy the Republic of Ireland. Such *political statements* are not a legal guarantee.

  - People who take those statements at face value should try to convince the Republic of Ireland, and then go to the other capitals with that endorsement.
  - People who believe that it will all come down to an eleventh hour backroom deal would disregard those statements and go directly to the major EU members.

Comment: Txs.  I found a full text @ [https://qz.com/943226/what-does-the-full-text-of-article-50-that-triggers-brexit-actually-say/](https://qz.com/943226/what-does-the-full-text-of-article-50-that-triggers-brexit-actually-say/)  I don't know, it's surprisingly short and it seems odd that extensions would need unanimity yet the modalities of withdrawal do not.  BTW, should that not be *Ireland*, rather than *Northern Ireland* in your statement above?

Comment: The EU guarantees and stands by the Good Friday Agreement.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosopher, of course. Fixed.

Comment: @o.m.  BTW, doesn't the (well known) member state capacity to threaten blackmail on unanimity rulings give Ireland an *implicit* (not explicit) veto here?  My understanding is the UK can't negotiate trade deals with 3rd parties until it leaves the EU.  And I don't think the Brexit deal covers trade yet either.  So a pissed-off Ireland could possibly be outvoted on article 50, but then could just veto any future UK to EU **trade** deal, could it not?  rendering victory Pyrrhic indeed.

Comment: +1 but the last point is a little more subtle than that. Other EU members do not back Ireland solely out of the goodness of their heart. Even if you assume it's essentially possible that the EU would ultimately throw Ireland under a bus in an 11th hour deal, a qualified majority requires more than just Germany and France, it requires the support of a host of other countries who are rightly afraid of German and French influence in the EU. Germany, France, or the UK would therefore need to sell it to them and avoid the impression that it is a compromise handed down from Berlin or Biarritz.

Comment: Also, the GFA allows NI born people to become citizens of the ROI at any point, but presumably only Remainers would take this option, so the negotiation mandate of the EU on behalf of NI citizens is a hard "make sure that NI remains in the EU". The EU throwing Ireland under the bus would not go unnoticed by citizens of other EU states.

Comment: @Evargalo, do you like the added links?

Comment: @Simon Richter there is no negotiating mandate of the EU  on behalf of NI. It is part of the UK, and as such has voted to leave.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons, not "on behalf of NI", but "on behalf of NI citizens". Some NI citizens are also EU citizens, and the EU has a duty toward these.

Comment: @SimonRichter being able to get RoI citizenship predates the GFA. Before that, the republic's government considered the whole island part of the country, so you got citizenship from birth. (after 2004, you have to have lineage. but otherwise the same)

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Depends who you ask in Northern Ireland.  Have you forgotten that many places in Northern Ireland regard themselves as wholly Irish, and not British?  Some Northern Irish folk take only a British passport, some take only an Irish.  Some take both, like me; and a record number identify as neither unionist nor nationalist these days.  Northern Ireland voted to stay.  We could have enjoyed a unique position as being in both the UK and EU by pushing the regulatory border to the Irish Sea, but our leaders decided otherwise.

Comment: @inappropiateCode it doesn't matter. The EU has no right of representation vis-a-vis deciding to mix in with deciding to represent people internally dissatisfied with the UK. As far as leaders deciding otherwise, that's because your 'unique position' is having an internal border in the UK belonging to another state-like entity; not reasonable in the slightest

Comment: @Simon Richter you're argument was "so the negotiation mandate of the EU on behalf of NI citizens is a hard "make sure that NI remains in the EU"' which Orwellian can be extended to mainland Britain as well. And of course their mandate from their UK citizens using your logic is "do everything to make sure Brexit happens" and of course, this is the larger mandate

Comment: To add to my last comment, the EU cannot decide they have mandates from subgroups of a country with regards of what a local majority want; I note that in all historical joining referenda the EU didn't say :oh region X has voted against Lisbon, let's follow their mandate and not integrate them'.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons, it cannot be extended to the whole of the UK because the EU citizenship of non-Irish citizens is through the UK (which is leaving), while the EU citizenship of Irish citizens is through the ROI, which is not planning to leave. NI Remainers have the right to remain EU citizens regardless of the referendum result, because that is an individual option guaranteed by the GFA, which the UK is signatory to, and which the referendum did not revoke.

Comment: The situation would be different if the Republic of Ireland also left the EU (because that would revoke the EU citizenship status of NI residents who took the ROI citizenship option), but we can assume that this is purely hypothetical.